# Undefined variable: data laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

**Route :**

```
Route::post('/store', [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'store']);
```

**View :**

```
<form action="/store" method="post">
@csrf
nom article <input type="text" name="titre" class="form-control mb-3"><br><br><br>
nom auteur <input type="text" name="nomAut" class="form-control mb-3"/><br><br><br>
contenu <input type="text" name="body" class="form-control mb-3"/><br><br><br>
<button class="btn btn-primary float-end px-5" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller :**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'titre'=>'required',
        'nomAut'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required',
    ]);

    Article::create($data);
    return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}
```

Comment: You are calling `$data` in  `Article::create($data);` (in the `store` function) but it's not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign `$data`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'titre'=>'required',
        'nomAut'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required',
    ]);

    Article::create($data);
    return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign $data like:

```
$data = $request->all()
```

Answer (score -1):

it's mutch better to require the fields from your form like this

```
<form action="/store" method="post">
    @csrf
    nom article <input type="text" name="titre" class="form-control mb-3" 
    required><br><br><br>
    nom auteur <input type="text" name="nomAut" class="form-control mb-3" 
    required/><br><br><br>
    contenu <input type="text" name="body" class="form-control mb-3" required/> 
    <br><br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary float-end px-5" 
    type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and your store methode :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $data = $request->all() ;

     Article::create($data);
     return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}
```

Comment: You totally wrong - backend MUST NOT TRUST any frontend input - because it's under full user control. What if I just delete "required" in code inspector, hm?